# Decoding json with a \n at the end

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to decode a json code:

```
"{\"id\":15,\"result\":true,\"error\":null}\n"
```

and this is my code:

```
def serverParse(data):
   jsonDat = json.loads(data)
   return json.dumps(data) + '\\n'
```

I've tried using data.replace('\n', ''), but it doesn't seem to work either. Is there a way I can parse it then reappend '\n' at return?

Comment: You have doubly-encoded JSON there, by the looks of it. If it was a Python string, it'd use `'{"id":15,"result":true,"error":null}\n'` and the newline wouldn't matter.

Comment: How was the JSON string you have produced? You probably want to fix the double encoding instead.

Comment: The trivial answer is `return json.dumps('{}\n'.format(jsonDat))`, but I want to know why do you have this function in the first place?

Comment: Why are you decoding then *encoding* again, as a matter of interest?

Comment: return json.dumps(data) + '\n'

Comment: @MartijnPieters There's some processing before return, but I'm only focused at the current matter.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have the code to process the 'id', but I've removed that A.T.M.

Comment: @KNgu: Then remove the `json.dumps()` line as it has nothing to do with decoding your input string and the line is confusing matters as it adds a `\\n` newline character to the end again. Personally, I am wondering why you'd even do that, add that newline character to the JSON output, as it would make your return value invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the newline character `\n` and the string `"\n"`. You need to replace the latter.

```
data = data.replace('\\n', '')
```

Comment: dat = data.replace('\\n', '')
jsonDat = json.loads(dat)

Does not work. :S

Answer (score 1):

Use `'\n'` instead of `'\\n'`.

```
>>> import json
>>> myjson = '{"id": 15, "result": true, "error": null}\n'
>>> json.dumps(json.loads(myjson)) + '\n'
'{"id": 15, "result": true, "error": null}\n'
```